a bit of searching on Twitter (that carousel, spinning ever faster, in a burning house)

In preparation for writing this essay, I did a bit of searching on Twitter (that carousel, spinning ever faster, in a burning house) for the phrase “AI Art.”

Source: https://www.thenation.com/article/culture/fordism-ai-art-dall-e/

Does "that" refer to the word right before it, "Twitter"?
Could "that carousel, spinning ever faster" be seen as "that carousel, which spins ever faster"?
What is the grammatical construction of the parenthetical insertion (that carousel, spinning ever faster, in a burning house)?


#2 is a correct reading; you can get a more useful answer if you edit to say why you had doubts about it. Re #1, I would say that the phrase "that carousel" refers to "Twitter"; depending on what you mean by "refer," I suppose "that" refers to "carousel."

"spinning ever faster" is an adjectival participle phrase. It means the same as "which is spinning ever faster" but it's a different grammatical construction. Note that words in brackets aren't part of the sentence and therefore don't necessarily have a grammatical relationship to the sentence, often being more like footnotes, although you can sometimes say "if the brackets weren't there, or were replaced by commas, it would have such-and-such a grammatical function". They should have a semantic relationship to the sentence, though:  in this case describing Twitter.

I don't think the fact that a parenthetical can be delivered as an "aside" necessarily divorces it from the syntax of the sentence. It's not as though it says something like  "... a bit of searching on Twitter (I wish I was the billionaire owner of such a company)". A parenthetical remark could do so, but in this case the syntax of the parenthetical dovetails.

The noun phrase "that carousel spinning ever faster in a burning house" stands in apposition to "Twitter". Both "Twitter" and the appositive noun phrase are objects of preposition on.
Compare:

I just paid off the credit card company, those usurers.

There, the noun phrases "the credit card company" and "those usurers" stand in apposition, both refer to the same entity, and both are direct objects of the transitive phrasal verb "paid off".
The participial clause spinning ever faster in a burning house is analyzed by some grammarians as a kind of elliptical relative clause whereas others consider it a clause type in its own right. On a semantic level in either analysis the behavior is ascribed to Twitter and the clause is understood to state what Twitter is doing (figuratively).
P.S. The demonstratives "that" and "those" do have additional meaning that "the" does not have. They put the entities referred to by those noun phrases ("that carousel..." and "those usurers") at some rhetorical/emotional "distance" from the speaker, to state it in very broad terms. They can express sarcasm, or contempt, or animus.

<that carousel, spinning ever faster, in a burning house> 1. Does the comma after "that carousel" indicate that what follows is non-restrictive, non-essential? 2. Is "spinning ever faster, in a burning house" part of the noun phrase even though it is non-restrictive, non-essential

The punctuation is the original is idiosyncratic. I would not venture to assign any clear meaning to it.  But I do not see that participial clause as restrictive. It is descriptive.

<that carousel, spinning ever faster, in a burning house> I'm not sure what you mean. I think that there should be a comma before "spinning ever faster, in a burning house" because "spinning ever faster, in a burning house" is non-essential, non-restrictive. What do I misunderstand?

That participial clause is not a restrictive relative clause by  virtue of its nature, not because there is no comma.   There is no need for a comma there.
